# $\left\{x:f(x)\neq 0\right\}$ decomposes into a numerable union of sets of finite measurement. with $f$ complex valued function and integrable.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f$ function with valued in $\mathbb{C}$ and $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. The set $\left\{x:f(x)\neq 0\right\}$  decomposes into a numerable union of sets of
Finite measurement.

I want
$\left\{x:f(x)\neq 0\right\}=\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \left\{x:|f(x)|>1/n\right\} $
But I do not know if this applies in this case with complex values ​​...

Comment: I have already corrected it

Comment: In which case the result is true, simply because  $f(x)=0$ iff there existed $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $|f| > 1/n $ (even for complex valued $f$)

Comment: (...should be $\neq 0$ instead of $=0$)

Comment: In mi notes,  say $f(x)\neq 0$...

Comment: I was correcting my comment that was too old for me to edit. Do you understand ?

Comment: oh! yes. sorry!